# SQL joins beginner

Tags: sql, join

I am quite new to sql and I am struggling with creating one query. I have two tables:

Character

- characterID
- firstname
- lastname
- gender

Couple

- coupleID
- femaleID
- maleID

Now I'm attempting to put it together like that:

- femaleFName
- femaleLName
- maleFName
- maleLName

I tried:

```
SELECT character.firstname AS femaleFName, character.lastname AS femaleLName
FROM Couple INNER JOIN Character ON Character.characterID = Couple.femaleID
```

but now I'm struggling with the second join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is join the table a second time. To do so, you have to provide aliases, so that the tables can not be confused.

```
SELECT 
cf.firstname AS femaleFName, cf.lastname AS femaleLName,
mf.firstname AS maleFName, mf.lastname AS maleLName
FROM Couple 
INNER JOIN Character AS cf ON cf.characterID = Couple.femaleID
INNER JOIN Character AS mf ON mf.characterID = Couple.maleID
```

The keyword `AS` is not mandatory though and can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `JOIN` like below. Here `c` is the table alias to differentiate the second join

```
SELECT character.firstname AS femaleFName, character.lastname AS femaleLName
FROM character INNER JOIN Couple ON Character.characterID = Couple.femaleID
INNER JOIN Couple c ON Character.characterID = c.maleID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use self join to get your desired results. Use following query to get results as you need.

```
Select cf.firstname as femaleFName,
cf.lastname as femaleLName,
cm.firstname as maleFName,
cm.lastname as maleLName
from Couple c 
inner join Character cf on c.femaleID = cf.characterID
inner join Character cm on c.maleID= cm.characterID
```

I hope this help you.

Thanks!